# ScrollViewer's scrolling control by coding in xaml.cs

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In windows phone app, I am try control the scrolling of ScrollViewer.In my requirements i wants to scroll the page when the my variable value is bla blaa. Is their any way to resolve this type of thing? please let me know .

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="-10,0,10,169">
            <StackPanel Height="916">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtNomeCliente" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"    
                    Text="" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <Button x:Name="BotaoCatalogo" Content="Catálogo"
                    Width="Auto" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3FAACA" BorderBrush="#FF3FAACA" />
                <Button x:Name="BotaoItens" Content="Itens"
                    Width="Auto" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3FAACA" BorderBrush="#FF3FAACA"/>
                <Grid Background="#FF0F3B48" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Qtde. de Itens:" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblQuantidadeProdutos" Text="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Width="43"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="2">

                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblValorTotal" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Button x:Name="BotaoPagamentos" Content="Adicionar Pagamento"
                    Width="Auto" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3FAACA" BorderBrush="#FF3FAACA"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="ListaPagamentos" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaPagamentos}"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="ListaEntrega" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaEntrega}"/>
                <Grid Background="#FF0F3B48" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">
                            <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="Forma de pagamento: A vista"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="16">
                            <Run Text="Parcela(s):"/>
                            <Run Text=" "/>
                            <Run Text="1"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="16">
                            <Run Text="Vencimento"/>
                            <Run Text=":"/>
                            <Run Text=" "/>
                            <Run Text="25/05/2013"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Margin="0">
                            <Run Text="    "/>
                            <Run Text="Valor"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="R$ 399,00" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <Button x:Name="cmdEntrega" Content="Entrega" Width="Auto" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3FAACA" BorderBrush="#FF3FAACA" />

                <Grid Background="#FF0F3B48" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="50">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="5,12,81,0" Height="38" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblTransportadora" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Width="149">
                            <Run FontSize="20" Text="Transportadora"/>
                            <Run FontSize="20" Text=":"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="13" Width="437"/>
                <Grid Background="#FF0F3B48" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="135">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="5,12,81,0" Height="38" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblTransportadora1" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Width="58" Margin="0,-2,0,12">
                            <Run FontSize="20" Text="Rua:"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Margin="5,11,128,85">
                        <Run FontSize="20" Text="Descrição:"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Margin="5,96,165,10">
                        <Run FontSize="20" Text="Cidade:"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblDescricao" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="113,16,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblRua" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="113,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblCidade" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="113,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="20" Width="437"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Informações Adicionais:" Margin="15,10,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="TxtInfoAdicional" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"    
                    Text="{Binding InfoAdicional, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White" BorderBrush="White"/>
                <Button x:Name="BotaoFinalizar" Content="Salvar Orçamento"
                    Width="238" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderBrush="#FF3FAACA" Background="#FF3FAACA"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The full XAML doesn't help at all since it is unclear what you want. Do you want to automatically scroll? Or you want to *prevent* scrolling if certain variable is set to certain value?

Comment: automatically scrolling works but i wants to handle scroll through coding like : if my variable value is 1 then scroll page on 0px and if my variable value is 2 then scroll page scroll down 10px vice versa for value 3 then down 10px more

Comment: So you want to scroll 10 times as much pixels as that variable is set?

Comment: Or you have a particular control in mind to scroll to?

Comment: wants to do this thing with some code in xaml.cs which control the scrolling

Comment: No, I ask you what is the formula. Is it 10 pixels for value, is it custom, does it depend on the controls in the view? To arbitrarily scroll down, see my answer below.

Comment: my code is : I have a timer, its run when page render , i want when timer value is 10 then scrollviewer scroll down 10px when timer value 20 then scrollviewer down 10px more

Comment: See my answer on how to scroll, it should be fairly easy for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arbitrarily scroll the scrollviewer, use `ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset`:

```
// scrolls down 10 pixels
ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(10);
```

EDIT:
You also need to change your XAML to:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
```

to make it accessible from the code behind.

Comment: this can be use in xaml.cs or xaml ?

Comment: That is obviously a C# code and can only be placed in .cs files.

Comment: its gives error :An object refrence is required for the non static field,method or property 'System.windows.controls.scrollViewer.scrolltoverticaloffeset(double)'

Comment: Well, you forgot to *name* your scroll viewer control in order to be accessible from the code behind.

Comment: will you please explain more how can i use this for upper given code.

Comment: See update. Also, please take some time to learn XAML basics.

Comment: i already use as like that but its not works like not accessible. Anyway thanks for the help friend.

Comment: No problem, please mark it as an answer if this answers your question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49147/discussion-between-sandeep-and-toni-petrina)